# PCB - Why to use Iron chloride?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

Soon, I'll try to create my own PCB with the iron chloride method. I watched a video on that and it seems quite "easy". The only thing that I don't understand is the need to put the PCB on the iron chloride solution. I read on Internet that it will "burn" the PCB but I don't really understand why it needs to be done as after, we remove all the iron particles from the PCB.

Can someone give me some information about that ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: It's also a chemistry question, not a design question.

Comment: Leon, I searched before posting... I just found that "http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=PCB+chloride+iron" where the "why" is not explained, so I don't understand why I get the "-1"... Anyway, I'll look elsewhere, thanks.

Comment: He didn't say "it's a duplicate", he said "you did no research".

Comment: No "burning" is involved; wherever you read that on the internet is misleading. http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2009/01/25/the-chemistry-of-home-etched-pcbs/ has the answer (and also tells you that ferric chloride is rubbish)

Comment: pjc50 > I'm french, so "burn" was not the good translation maybe. Thanks for the link, I'll read it. 

Ignacio > I did some research, I even said in my post that "I read on Internet..."... That means I searched for the information, but as I said, I just found the "what", not the "why"... Anyway...

Comment: Ah, this is a bad translation of "oxidise" (it's a redox reaction) then.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know about this word. Thanks for your help. How an I flag your answer as a valid answer when it is a comment ?

Comment: I've added a proper answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before being placed into the solution, the board is lined with a solid layer of copper. Unwanted copper must be removed, so that only the circuit artwork remains.

Although prior to the immersion in ferric chloride, it looks like the board already has a finished circuit on it, the artwork which you see is still only a mask printed on top of a single piece of copper foil which lines the entire surface of the board, allowing electricity to be conducted between any two points on the board.

When we place the board in the solution, the chemical reaction between the exposed copper and the ferric chloride causes the exposed copper to be leached away. Given enough time, it is completely leached away, revealing the bare epoxy board underneath.  What remains on the board is the copper that is protected by the mask corresponding to the artwork.

At that point, we have the connections for a circuit: the PCB artwork which we designed on the computer screen (or perhaps in some other way) is now manufactured out of conductive copper, adhering to a rigid, non-conductive epoxy or phenolic board which gives it durability. The board is now thoroughly rinsed so that no traces of the chemical solution remain, and the mask can finally be removed, revealing shiny copper.

Although PCB's are called printed circuit boards, they are actually "printed and etched circuit boards". Another way to make a board is by means of a CNC (computer numeric control) milling machine.  This is not really printing at all; rather a tool holding a rotating cutting bit is precisely guided by a computer to remove unwanted copper, leaving behind the shape of the circuit artwork.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the answer I was looking for. I wasn't aware that the copper where there is no artwork would be leached away so I didn't understand why the whole piece would not have been conductive. It is very clear with your explanation, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

[This link](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2009/01/25/the-chemistry-of-home-etched-pcbs/) has the answer (and also tells you that ferric chloride is not the best choice as it's not reusable)

The core answer is that it performs a redox reaction:

> 2 Fe(3+) + Cu(0) –> 2 Fe(2+) + Cu(2+)

That turns copper metal on the exposed PCB into copper ions that dissolve in the etchant, removing copper from areas of the PCB not covered by the "mask" that was applied photographically earlier in the process.